# How can I translate in the CLI an English word into a German one?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, dictionary, natural-language

I want to write a Script that picks a random English word from `/usr/share/dict/words`, translates it into German, display both of them for a certain amount of time and repeat the process. I only know the beginning part and do not know how to use a word to word translation in the shell:

```
watch -n5 sh -c 'cat /usr/share/dict/words | shuf -n1 | .....'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Download **Translate Shell***

```
cd
wget https://github.com/soimort/google-translate-cli/archive/master.tar.gz
tar -xvf master.tar.gz
cd google-translate-cli-master/
```

*Install*

- use `make`

  ```
  sudo make install
  ```

  **OR**
- use `checkinstall`

  ```
  sudo apt-get install checkinstall
  sudo checkinstall
  ```

  If you see this: `3 -  Version: [ master ]`then

  - Press <kbd>3</kbd>
  - Enter a number, e.g. `20150330`
  - Press <kbd>Return</kbd>

*Translate with*

```
cat /usr/share/dict/words | shuf -n1 | tee >( xargs -0 trs {=de} | xargs echo) | xargs -0 echo -n
```

***Your command***

```
watch -n5 'bash -c "cat /usr/share/dict/words | shuf -n1 | tee >( xargs -0 trs {=de} | xargs echo) | xargs -0 echo -n"'
```

Comment: why do you use the -0 option ?

Comment: what is the purpose of this >(......) structure ?

Comment: xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option

Comment: tee is used to split the output of a program

Comment: i know tee but i do not know the >(.....) structure.   I have copied your code into the shell, there must be somewhere bug, because the output shows me two lines of the same german word.

Comment: Sorry, I had tested it with `zsh`. Now it should work with `bash`.